# Tetrahedron congruence theorems

Tags: geometry, triangles

I’m researching tetratomic molecules and tetrahedra have consequently become a subject of interest.

I’m seeking to prove equivalent congruence theorems for tetrahedra to those for triangles.

Has any research been published on this subject?

I’ve proved that 6 same edge lengths is equivalent to congruence.
My theories are that:

- 6 same planar angles, arranged as 2 each on 3 different faces is equivalent to similarity of tetrahedra
- 6 same dihedral angles is equivalent to similarity
- 5 edges and a planar angle; 4 edges and 2 planar angles; or 3 edges and 3 planar angles are equivalent to congruence

I’m uncertain about the case of 2 edges and 4 planar angles.
Does the disposition of those edges and planar angles have to be specified to be the same?

Are there any other combinations of elements (e.g. face areas and dihedral angles, or face areas and edges, or dihedral and planar angles) that show congruence or similarity?

It seems that 6 elements are necessary and sufficient to prove congruence or similarity (akin to the 3 needed for triangles).

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "pieces". For instance, knowing two faces and their dihedral angle (3 pieces) is enough.

Comment: 4 vertices, 6 edges, 12 planar angles, 6 dihedral angles and various other properties.  https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ATheoremOnTheDihedralAnglesOfATetrahedron/ is one dihedral theorem.  There is likely room for exploration with this problem.

Comment: Six *appropriately-chosen* pieces of info will do. The six edge-lengths; three "concurrent" edge-lengths and the three (planar) angles between pairs of them; three face *areas* and the three *dihedral* angles between pairs of them; four face areas alone aren't enough, but including the three of what I call "pseudoface" areas will do. (A pseudoface is the shadow of the tetrahedron in a plane parallel to a pair of opposite edges. The seven values are related by "sum-of-squares-of-face-areas = sum-of-squares-of-pseudoface-areas", so that there are only six *independent* values.) Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I haven't formally published anything, but I've archived a bit of on-gong research into "hedronometry" (the dimensionally-enhanced trigonometry of tetrahedra), both Euclidean and non-, [here](http://hedronometry.com).

Comment: Thanks. I've drafted a proof of the 6 edge-lengths case. I'm struggling slightly with the rest.

Comment: @TheorVHP: The 6 edges case is straightforward (but requires specifying the arrangement): 3 edges determine a unique triangle (Side-Side-Side congruence), so all face-shapes are known and make a unique tet (ignoring orientation). Likewise, you can mix-and-match edges and face-angles that make Side-Side-Side and Side-Angle-Side congruence patterns; again, arrangement matters. The 6 dihedral-angle similarity case follows from the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), which in this context converts dihedral-angle info into face-angle info.